# "das" statt "die" obwohl das Subjekt eine Frau ist?

Tags: demonstrative-pronoun

> Eine Frau steigt aus dem Auto. Peter hat das soeben beobachtet und teilt seinen Kollegen mit: "***Das*** ist Anna Pilsen."

Frage: Weshalb wird hier "das" verwendet, obwohl es sich doch um eine Frau handelt? Wie lautet die Regel für die Verwendung von "das" in diesem Beispiel?

Weshalb sagt man nicht:

- Die ist Anna Pilsen.   Oder:
- Diese ist Anna Pilsen.

Comment: Weil "das" im Deutschen nicht nur ein sächlicher Artikel sondern auch ein Demonstrativpronomen ist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anstelle von *das* könnte man *die da* sagen, das ist aber unüblich.

Tatsächlich vertritt **das** als Demonstrativpronomen an dieser Stelle das Ersatzsubjekt **es**. Und **es** ist sächlich.

> **Es** steigt Anna Pilsen aus dem Auto.
>
> **Es** handelt sich um Anna Pilsen.
>
> **Es** ist Anna Pilsen.
>
> **Das** ist Anna Pilsen.

Im Englischen im Übrigen genau gleich:

> It's Anna Pilsen.

Comment: Oder sogar noch wörtlicher: _This is Anna Pilsen_.

Comment: "Die ist Anna Pilsen" ist weder falsch noch in erster Linie "unüblich". Es ist ganz einfach schlechtes Benehmen. Es gehört sich nicht, über einen Anwesenden in der 3. Person zu sprechen. Das "Das" schwächt die 3. Person im Rahmen des Möglichen ab.