# Why is the sentence "Das ist eine Nase" correct?

Tags: gender, article

I'm doing some homework, in which we have pictures and we have to complete the sentences like "Ist das **ein** Salat?" - "Nein, das ist **kein** Salat. Das ist **ein** Bus."

In the example above, both Salat and Bus get the article "ein", so I get why the answer is "**das** ist". But Nase is feminine, so it gets "eine". Why it is correct to say "**Das** ist eine Nase", and not "**Die** ist eine Nase"?

Comment: Aw, I wish your teach asked you, "Ist das ein Mond?", so you would have to answer in the negative...

Comment: Hat jemand meinen Kommentar gelöscht? Ich fände es sinnvoll, den Fragesteller darauf hinzuweisen, daß *Salat* und *Bus* keine Neutra sind.

Comment: A bit tangentially, it's perhaps worth pointing out that there's no expectation for _X_ and _Y_ in the sentence "_X_ ist _Y_" to agree in gender anyway: "Die Nase ist ein Körperteil" is a perfectly fine and reasonable thing to say, even though _die Nase_ is grammatically feminine and _der Körperteil_ is masculine.

Comment: Similar question in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35859/das-statt-die-obwohl-das-subjekt-eine-frau-ist

Answer (score 31):

In German language, the word "*das*" is not only an article. It has a second meaning:

It can also have the meanings of the English words "*this*" or "*that*".

If the word "*das*" means "*this*", there are no different words for male, female and neuter but there is only one word: "*das*".

In your sentence, the word "*das*" is not used as article but it means "*this*".

---

By the way:

The word "*der*" sometimes has the meaning: "*this man*" and the word "*die*" sometimes has the meaning "*this woman*".

So the sentence: "*Die ist eine Nase.*" would mean: "*This woman is a nose.*"

Articles can also refer to a word in a sentence before:

> Auf diesen Bildern sind **Teile** des Körpers zu sehen. **Der** hier ist eine Nase.

In this case, "*der*" would be an abbreviation of "*dieser Teil*" ("*this part*"). The gender (*der/die/das*") would be specified by the gender of the word "*Teil*" in this case and not by the gender of the word "*Nase*".

Comment: I do like your answer, but the example with _Körperteile_ sounds strange to me. Maybe because the number (plural _vs_ singular) doesn't match. Maybe there is a better example...

Comment: I concur the example doesn't really make a lot of sense; You can't really have a backreference to a singular thing when you only mentioned a plural set of things before. You could say something like "Einer von **diesen** ist eine Nase", but that's quite different. It's not the only problem though, even if you had singular you'd use  "dieser" in the following sentence, although you'd use "der" in side sentence like "Dies ist ein Körperteil **der** eine Nase ist".

Comment: *der* is no abbreviation, i dare say it's not even a reduction of *dieser*.

Comment: @Cubic I changed the example. It should be better now.

Comment: >"You can't really have a backreference to a singular thing when you only mentioned a plural set of things before." Of course you can, the sentence with _Körperteile_ is absolutely correct.

Comment: @sentence *absolutely* is a very strong word. It's not consistent.

Comment: The problem why this feels wrong is that the gender of "Körperteil" is kind of disputed. Duden claims "der", but it's wrong, it's "das" ;) At least that will sound more natural to many. And thus the example with "der" will sound unnatural/wrong to the respective group of Germans. Use something where the gender is clear, e.g. it should work well with "Briefmarken" and "Die" in that case. Though it is always somewhat colloquial (i.e. compared to using "Diese" if you take the suggested example) and thus may come off as strange depending on whether this form is common in the local dialect.

Comment: @FrankHopkins I edited my answer and changed it to "Teile des Körpers" so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 12):

Quite as in English:

> That's a house. That's a beer. That's a girl. That's a boy. That's a nose. That's a leg. That's a liver. That's a stallion. That's a mare. That's a flower. That's a ship.

Genus just does not play a role here. (Nor does sex.)

Note that by tradition, ships in English are referred to as females:

> That's the Queen Mary. The Queen Mary is 300 metres long. She (!) has four chimneys.

Theoretical explanation: You can see the *Das* as the equivalent of the English *That*: as a demonstrative pronoun, not as an indicator of genus. Under this perspective, the *das* here is a different *das* than in *der, die, das*. But that's really a theoretical consideration with not too much relevance for using the language in everyday life. For everyday life you simple get used to saying *Das ist eine Frau* although the *Frau* is female by genus (and probably also by sex).

Note additionally perhaps:

> That's milk.

Yeah, you do not count milk, and in these cases you go without the definite article. Same in German:

> Das ist Milch.

But:

> Das ist ein Glas Milch.

Comment: Note that it may be perceived as root to be called "das".

Comment: @vectory Do you mean as rude?

Comment: The analogy to English isn't really helpful. English doesn't have grammatical gender in the same way German does. In particular, English has no gender declension of articles . "As in English" would mislead you about  "That's *the* girl" and "That's *the* boy". (*"Nein, das ist nicht das Salat. Das ist das Nase."*) The core confusion here is the distinction between different usages of  "das", one where it's declined for gender and one where it's not - a distinction which has no counterpart in English.

Comment: @R.M. English also distinguishes between "It's a girl" and "She's a girl", or was that not what you meant?

Comment: @R.M. The useful part of the analogy is that English (and most languages) distinguishes "that" and "the" where German just uses "das".

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty simple, because *das* explicitly doesn't refer to the nose that was in context. This "das" is an indefinite pronoun and thus does not receive a gender, but defaults to neutral, inanimate gender. We might also use "dies", "es", or even "so-etwas" ("Sowas ist doch nicht normal").

If talkling about people instead, we would make a difference, "Nein, Sie ist keine Nase", and we might use gendered articles as pronouns, too, e.g. "die", shortened from "die Frau", or "Der ist so schlau, der vectory".

We only refer to a specific gender, if it's already in context, but it just doesn't work well with negatives. Hence:

> Das ist gar keine Frage
>
> Das ist ja wohl unerhört

Vice-versa, we may use the indefinite pronoun for positive statements, pretty much by analogy

> Ja, das ist ein Golden-Retriever

Which is unproblematic because in most cases we could surmise a neutral noun to fit, e.g. "das Tier".

Further:

*dies* seems to be a mix of both *die* and *das*, in case you can't decide :) but we also have the anaphoras "dies und das", and "dieses und jenes".

*es* actually stems from a meaning "here".

Combining both we get *dieses ist keine Nase* (which sounds a bit like ellipses of *dieses Ding*). We would not say *diese* (female) in such cases, however.

*etwas*--I found nothing concrete about it--may by my estimate be in part from *es*, PGmc *hit "that", PIE *ke-, *key- "this, here", too, bound with "was" cp. "Ich habe hier etwas", "look at this here".

Comment: How is *das* indefinite? Does *das* "not receive a gender" or is it "neutral"? What gender difference is there supposed to be between *das ist eine Frage* und *das ist keine Frage*? How is *dies* a mixture of *die* feminine and *das* neuter?

Comment: @DavidVogt a) Is *indefinite pronoun* not applicable here? I've seen that term as label for "it rains" I'm aware that different explanations may be given, but I prefer this one. b) If *das* in that position does not contrast with other gender, then the gender distinction is meaningless. c) Did I say there was a difference? refer to b. d) I have not read anything intricate on the formation of the articles, pronouns etc. I think you do understand what ":)"

Comment: a) *Demonstrative pronoun*, b) but it does contrast with *die/der*, as you point out yourself, c) then what is the difference between the negated and the non-negated sentence in this context?, d) smiley notwithstanding, it might mislead the OP.

Comment: b) no, not if parsed as a different syntactic entity. c) It's likely to have arisen from the negation, I guess. It's an interesting question. d) It's not misleading, synchronically it's a likely lexicalization.

Comment: b) I don't see the difference, c) you need to show how you got to this conclusion, it's far from self-evident, d) fusing feminine and neuter pronouns together does seem the opposite of likely to me.

Comment: @DavidVogt d) as English shows, not.

Comment: Well chucks, English still does differentiate "this and that", so yeah. Very very weird. :)

Comment: d) English *that* is a descendant of neut. δæt. There was no "mixing" involved.

Comment: @DavidVogt I was affraid I wasn't clear. Obviously English fused gender in the definite article and many other places. That happened not just by exluding "that" from the paradigm, which had full inflection, but mysteriously, \*se moved to *th*, which is an irregular sound shift, so that it's safe to say the phonetics too had fused. This doesn't say very much about "die", which may be an independent or at least parallel development. But that wasn't the point of that specific remark. "this and that", "dies und das" implies that the distinction was shared. Which doesn't make it easier to analyze.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the claim of *dies* being *die* + *das*.

Comment: Well, now I caught myself in a corner, missing the distinction between article and pronoun, that I maintained before. Let's say the diachronic argument is a different one.